# Jest ignore jsdoc documentation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Is there any way for jest to ignore comments?

For example:

`index.js`

```js
/**
 * Calculates a sum of all givens numbers
 * 
 * @example sum(1,1); // 2
 * @example sum(1,2,-5,2.4,-6.5); // -6.1
 * @example sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0); // 45
 * @example sum(-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-9); // 25
 * 
 * @param  {...number} numbers - the numbers to sum
 * @returns {number} summ of all numbers
 * 
 * @function sum
 */
export function sum(...numbers) {
    return numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}
```

Coverage output:

```
File     | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
---------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------
index.js |   88.23 |      100 |       0 |   88.23 | 16-17
```

At this moment, as you can see in the table, several lines appear as having already been tested, but none have been tested yet. Any idea how to resolve this?

The output that I expected it’s a table like this:

```
File     | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
---------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------
index.js |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | ...
```

Thanks any help :)

There is a project example: https://bitbucket.org/flavio-silva-mindera/jest-ignore-jsdoc/

Comment: Your question is still not clear. `several lines appear as having already been tested, but none have been tested yet` Can you explain this statement?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening (sorry I'm still a noob, on jest/testing )

Comment: @BadPiggie hey again, based on what you said, I created an example project of my problem: https://bitbucket.org/flaviosilvaa/jest-ignore-jsdoc/